# Is there a pattern for deserialization involving repository access? Or what is wrong with my design?

Tags: scala, domain-driven-design, deserialization, playframework-2.3

Let us have

```
case class Money(amount: BigDecimal, currency: Currency)
case class Currency(code: String, alpha3: String)
```

`Money` is a value object and `Currency` is an entity. 
When transforming `Money` to JSON I would replace currency with its code. However revers operation requires repository access (which is implemented using `Future`). Is there something wrong with my design? Should I introduce `CurrencyCode` value-object?

Answer (score 0):

> Currency is an entity

Yes, it may be, but in which bounded context? Usually, Money and Currency are generic concepts and value objects in your **core** bounded context. A business/domain concept may live in multiple bounded contexts and plays different roles (entity/value object). You have to ask "Does this bounded context really care about the life cycle of this object?".